# sed - insert lines when text found / not found

Tags: sed

I have issue with sed, i need to accomplish two things with a csv file

1. in front of each line that does not start UNES I need to add tag "BF2;"
2. at the start of the file (after UNES if present) I need to add a tag "UNH;"

Example (no UNES;)

```
50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangift;
50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangifte;
50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangifte;
```

Example (with UNES;)

```
UNES;
50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangift;
50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangifte;
50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangifte;
```

so far I have this:

```
sed -e 's/^\([^"UNES"]\)/BF2;\1/' | sed '/UNES/ a\UNH;'
```

THis works as long as a UNES; tag is present - I can't seem to figure out how to insert the UNH; when UNES is not present!

Any help much appreciated

Sample output:

```
UNES;
UNH;
BF2;50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangifte;
BF2;50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangifte;
BF2;50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangifte;
```

Comment: What is `NCTS-(TA) ` which was present in the middle?

Comment: It's just fluff - I'll edit so it looks like the original input - my bad sorry in a huge rush as usual!

Comment: What if the UNES is not present at the top?

Comment: if not present in the original message then it should not be added to the output. So far the first command works when it is not present, I can't figure out how to add UNH; part

Comment: a colleague just bailed me out - this seems to work a treat:<br>|sed -e '1s/^\(UNES.*$\)/\1\nUNH;/' -e '1,$s/^\([^"UNES"]\)/BF2;\1/' -e '1s/^\(BF2.*$\)/UNH;\n\1/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you could do it using awk:

```
awk 'NR==1 {if(f=/^UNES;/)print; print "UNH;"} !f{print "BF2;" $0} {f=0}' file
```

On the first line, if /^UNES;/ is matched, `print` it and set the flag `f`. Always print "UNH;". If the `f` flag has been set, don't do the next action, which works for the rest of the lines. Always reset `f` to 0 after the first line so all further lines have "BF2;" added to the start.

Testing it out:

```
$ cat file
UNES;
50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangift;
50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangifte;
50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangifte;
$ awk 'NR==1 {if(f=/^UNES;/)print; print "UNH;"} !f{print "BF2;" $0} {f=0}' file
UNES;
UNH;
BF2;50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangift;
BF2;50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangifte;
BF2;50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangifte;
$ cat file2
50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangift;
50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangifte;
50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangifte;
$ awk 'NR==1 {if(f=/^UNES;/)print; print "UNH;"} !f{print "BF2;" $0} {f=0}' file2
UNH;
BF2;50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangift;
BF2;50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangifte;
BF2;50000024;IE15;041111;113901;verstuurd;Aangifte;
```

Comment: hi ya and thanks, this only seems to work when UNES is present in the file. I need to be able to process files that do not contain UNES as well and then UNH; is added at the start and BF2; to the beginning of every other line

Comment: So always add "UNH;" but below "UNES;" if that's already there?

Comment: I have altered the code so that it does what you want now.

Comment: brilliant - cheers I appreciate it - quickly onto my next crisis :)

Comment: wee bit shorter `awk '{f=/^UNES;/;print f?$0"\nUNH;":"BF2;"$0}' file`

Comment: @Jidder thanks for the suggestion, I was going to include it but the output is different to what the OP is looking for when "UNES;" is missing from the top of the file.

Comment: @TomFenech Oh yeah, this should work but it looks a bit a of a mess so i don't know if it would be as useful. `awk '{print /^UNES;/?$0"\nUNH;":(NR==1?"UNH;\n":x)"BF2;"$0}' file`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sed command:

```
sed '/^UNES;$/{i\
UNH;
n};s/^/BF2;/;' file.txt
```

details:

`/^UNES;$/i\
UNH;` insert a new line when UNES; is the whole line.

`n` replaces the pattern space with the next line

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its works for me

```
sed '/^UNES;$/{i\
UNH;
n};s/^[0-9]*/BF2;&/;'
```